# Link to a another Python file in the comments

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, pycharm, python-sphinx

I am trying to create a link to `file2.py` from `file_1.py`. For simplicity we can assume both are in the same package.

What I would do in Java (via Intellij) is using `{@link AnotherClass}` but this is not possible in Python comment (or Pycharm):

[image]

I also tried to use `Sphinx` and though it is possible to make such links with something like `:py:mod:'my.package.file2'` this doesn't work for me since I cannot use an IDE to navigate to the file and I also cannot generate these links easily since there is no autocomplete available to auto-generate the full module path.

Is there any other option I am missing? I am not restricted to any particulare IDE/Editor or any link format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links)

Add this to your `settings.json`

```
  "html-related-links.include": {
    "python": [
      { "find": "\\{@link ([^}]+)\\}';", "filePath": "$1.py" }
    ]
  }
```

Now all the linked files are shown in the **Related Files** view in the Explorer bar (`Ctrl+Shift+E`). You can create files that do not exist yet by clicking on the create file icon in the view. Or when you try to open a non existing file you have to option to create it (button in the message).

I will try to make these new type of links Ctrl-clickable.

Comment: sounds useful, but this is for visual studio users, anything for pycharm users?

Comment: Epytext like link format works well for pycharm

f"""
        L{bin.predict.refine_predict()}
"""

Comment: @riversun what is the need of the `"""`

Comment: """ is a docstring used in Python to describe the purpose and usage of functions, classes, and modules. By including the `L{}` notation within the docstring, it becomes ctrl+clickable in PyCharm.

Comment: @riversun `"""` is a docstring: that is not true, read the doc what a docstring is